# Did ansible support ssh client configuration

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

If I login to a remote host free password by command:
`/usr/bin/ssh -i ~/.ssh/test.private.pem -F /etc/dssh_config $remote_host`. 
How can I configure the ansible to support it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific section about [ssh args](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#ssh-args) in the official documentation.

You can pass your arguments in `ansible.cfg`

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -i ~/.ssh/test.private.pem -F /etc/dssh_config
```

The [configuration file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#getting-the-latest-configuration) can be found (post 1.5) (in priority order)

- ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable)
- ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
- .ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
- /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

Comment: Thanks for help. I am the new guy of ansible. I'm not yum install ansible but compile and install the source. My ansible's bin file is in /home/$my-account/python/bin/ansible(python setup.py install). So where I can write this config file?